# How to know if the player shared my link on a social app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, social-networking

I am using Unity3d and C# scripts/code. I just started to use Native share plugin by Yasirkula.

Here is part of my code:

```
NativeShare().SetSubject( "Check out this game!" ).SetText( "Link to my app here" ).Share();
```

When I reach this line the user sees a sharing menu, and he can choose any sharing app he wishes. How to make sure that the user actually shared the link on Whatsapp, FaceBook, Twiter and not using his clipboard or any other app? I want to reward the user only on a real social share.

Comment: I think is not possible to do that, mostly because there is a security barrier. Since a user clicks to accepts to share, the users enter the selected app and your program can recive "that" feedback. After that, you are running a different app and, commonly, it does not send you a feedback if he accepted send or not, by personal privacy.

Comment: You sure? I think there must be a solution for this.

Comment: At least not that way, `NativeShare().Share()` returns `void`, so no

Comment: try it on any known app/game, they cannot check if you actually shared or just pressed back, you still get the rewards.

Comment: So...how can I solve it? I want to make sure that the user actually share. No back button or any other non-sharing is good.

Comment: You can't do it. It is specifically against most, if not all, social sites' TOS to incentivise shares.  Even if you found a way, it would be a bug that would probably get patched at some point and break your code.

Comment: Use each social website API to track is the user share your application as @Fredrik Widerberg is suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native Share has a way to choose what app you want to share with, but it's Android only:

```
// Share on WhatsApp only, if installed (Android only)
if( NativeShare.TargetExists( "com.whatsapp" ) )
        new NativeShare().AddFile( filePath ).SetText( "Hello world!" ).SetTarget( "com.whatsapp" ).Share();
```

With this, you could make one button for each app you want to allow the user to share with, preventing sharing with non-social apps. I think this is the closest you can get of what you want.

Unfortunately I don't know if there are any workarounds for iOS and cancel/back button.

Comment: Nathalia, I like your answer. But how can I be sure that the player hasn't press the back/exit button and closeed the share option?

Comment: As I said, unfortunately I don't know if this is possible. I know that with Native Share it's not.

Comment: You know how to attack my problem without NativeShare? With any means?

Comment: No, I don't know... The other answers lead me to believe that this is not possible. Even if you figure out some native code that tells you if the person closed the sharing dialog before actually share, you woudn't be able to know if he or she canceled the sharing **inside** the social app. Miguel's idea looks like the most viable way to do this, but it will only work if the link is clicked by the receiver, for what I understood.

Comment: Maybe specific APIs like suggested by Frederik could solve your problem.

Comment: Can you help me find a "one stop shop"? Validation that sharing actually made and via a social app...

Comment: Sorry, I can't. If you have any specific questions, I'll be glad to answer - _if_ I know the answer. But I can't do any research for you.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of marketing emails use this technique to trace emails status:

The raw idea is to put a parameter in the URL that will be shared and track when this URL is used to access your application.

The parameter can be a cryptographic nonce with useful information. When you receive a request with that URL you decrypt the nonce and use this data to identify the user sharing the link.

[Here](https://www.hubspot.com/sales/email-tracking-guide) you can investigate how this pattern is applied to trace email status (open, read, etc...)

Comment: @Tal Angel I can confirm this is the appropriate way to go about the problem. The only detail is, you need the receiver of the shared link to click on it, in order to know if it was shared. So in theory you wouldn't ever get direct feedback if the share was successful.

Answer (score 1):

An out of the box idea:

Turn

`NativeShare().SetSubject( "Check out this game!" ).SetText( "Link to my app here" ).Share();`

into

`NativeShare().SetSubject( "Check out this game!" ).SetText( "Link to my app here #trackablehashtag" ).Share();`

Then you can crawl social with a search for your hashtag, or use the built in social media marketing tools to track trends. Although this may not be a complete solution to your problem, it may have some added benefit a full solution may not create itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at the Facebook Unity API?

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity

There is a method called `FB.FeedShare`

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare

```
FB.FeedShare(
    link: new Uri("Link"),
    linkName: "Oh la la",
    callback: Callback
);
```

There is also one called `FB.ShareLink`

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ShareLink

```
FB.ShareLink(
    new Uri("Link"),
    callback: Callback
);
```

Looking at the callback parameter for these two, `IShareResult`, it has both a `bool Cancelled` and a `string PostId`

So you could possibly do this

```
void Callback(IShareResult result)
{
    if (result.Cancelled || result.PostId == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("No reward for you");
    }            
}
```

I say possibly, because i havent tested this myself.

Comment: You only talk about Facebook. I want to allow my player to share via any social app, and I want to verify that he really did so.